# How place correctly title of column above column Dataframe Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I realized Pandas Dataframe and converted this to csv with some columns but my columns titles are not above my column in csv file...

```
dataframe_tri.to_csv('E_value_max.txt',sep ='\t', mode = 'w', index = None)
```

How to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

I can't post picture so, my file is like that, but columns are separate by tab :

ColumnA    ColumnB     ColumnC    ColumnD
blablablablablablablabla    22     blopblopblopblop    23
blablablablablablablabla    22     blopblopblopblop    23

Comment: your columns are in the correct position, they are seperated by a tab?

Comment: I have create my dataframe like this, without precision of separator, just precision to convert in csv.



<code> data = {'Num_id_align' : list_id, 'Query cover' : list_query_cover,  'E_value' : list_e_value,'Per Id' : list_perc_id, 'Accession' : list_accession} <code>



<code> dataframe_hits = pd.DataFrame(data) <code>

Comment: Sorry I can’t place the code tags correctly :X

Answer (score 0):

while writing dataframe to csv you don't have to worry about seperator

```
dataframe_tri.to_csv('E_value_max.txt', index = False)
```

Comment: If I don't specify separator, separator by default is comma, and that doesn't solve my problem :/